# SQL Complex Summation

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
data,   ID, Value,  Exp1

201101, 1,  2   
201202, 1,  3   
201303, 1,  4   
201101, 2,  2   
201202, 2,  3   
201303, 2,  4   
201304, 2,  5   
201305, 2,  6   
201306, 2,  7   
201307, 2,  8   
201308, 2,  9   
201309, 2,  10  
201310, 2,  11  
201311, 2,  12  
201312, 2,  13
```

I have to calculate the value of Exp1 as

for `ID=2`. `Exp1= (sum of value from 201307 to 201312)/6-(sum of value from 201301 to 201306)/6`

Some IDs might not have value for all the months, some might have only one value.

Is this  possible in `SQL`?

for ID 2: Exp1=(13+12+11+10+9+8)/6-(7+6+5+4+3+2)/6

for ID 1: Exp1=(0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0)/6-(2+3+4+0+0+0)/6

This has to be done for all the IDS

Comment: I want to calculate the value for Exp1 for Each ID as following:     for ID 2, i have to calculate (sum of the all 'value' from July to december)/6-(sum of all the 'value' from January to June)/6

Comment: Why from 201307 to 201312?Can you explain the logic?Split the number of rows with id=2 in half?

Comment: Give an example for id 1 also.

Comment: What if its an id which has more than 12 rows?

Comment: Each ID will have only 12 rows,some id might have only one row

Comment: Did you mess your ids in your last edit?

Comment: where there are less than 12 rows do you still want to divide by 6 or by the number of rows?

Comment: I have updated the table @ Mihai. Yes I still want to divide by 6 even if there is only 1 row.

Comment: Here is a fiddle,I coudn`t crack it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b84b3

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
ID,
sum(
    case 
      when YRMO between 201307 and 201312 then value 
      else 0 
    end)/6 
- sum(
    case 
      when YRMO between 201301 and 201306 then value 
      else 0 
    end)/6 as EXP1

from TABLE
group by ID;
```

Comment: Updated - removed where clause to deal with all ID values

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  id, 
  sum(value) / 6 exp1
from (
  select 
    id, 
    case when YRMO between '201301' and '201306' then -value else value end value
  from `table`
  where YRMO between '201301' and '201312' 

) q
group by id
```